# I want to output numbers 1-10 using JavaScript but when I click start it literally doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

Literally just want my webpage to output numbers 1-10 in a loop. What am I doing wrong guys

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript Example</title>
  <script>
    "use strict";
    function start() {
      var c;
      for (c = 0; c <= 10; c++) {
        window.alert(c);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="start()">start</button>
  <p>Javascript Test Page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From the [`java` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info): "*Java (**not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS**) ...*". From the [`javascript` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*JavaScript (**not to be confused with Java**) ...*"

Comment: `alert` is a blocking function. Use `console.log` for debugging. Note that you're also starting at 0, which will be included in your loop. 0-10 currently outputs, not 1-10

Comment: Your code works perfectly as-is, aside from the fact that it also outputs 0. Now that @blex has put your HTML into a stack snippet, you can run it for yourself and see.

Comment: Yes I was for some reason testing the wrong file. How else can I output the numbers without an alert. @sterlingArcher says to use console.log but I have never used this and do not know where to put it.

Comment: @Phil sounds like you have some research to do on JS interacting with the DOM, and basic debugging. Please look up the javascript console and how to use it, and then you'll have to learn how to create dynamic HTML elements and then how to insert them on your page. There's great resource material you can look for to help you, like the docs. Here's one of the functions you'll need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild good luck! :)